# Kendo grid Pager buttons disappear

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have the following jQuery code on Search button click to read kendo grid data source but for some reason the pager buttons disappear

```
  function onSearchButtonClick() {
      var grid = $('#searchProducts').data('kendoGrid');
        var gridDS = grid.dataSource;
            gridDS.read();
  }
```

On Search button click display all the data and the grid Pager shows only the following P

[image]

The highlighted sections are missing, this happend when i uses `datasource.read()`
[image]

Comment: I believe this has to do with the grid's responsive behavior not working properly. The first pic is what the pager looks like on small screens. Try calling the grid's `resize` method after the page fully loads or possibly in the `DataBound` event.

Comment: Is this resolved?